# How to call a sub hash($) function

Tags: regex, perl, hash

Here is a source-code of a short program:

http://info.fenster.name/misc/task_hash.pm.txt

there's a comment

Usage: `$hashref = hash($sourcecode);`

but I have no experience with Perl.

Please, write an example, how to invoke those function, for example, with string `«#include <iostream> int main(){return 0;}»`

**upd. code:**

**sub hash($)
{
...
}
how to invoke it?**

Comment: You should ask a question about programming, including the source code you want to ask about. (Not an entire program on an external link, which nobody is going to read)

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to assign the string `#include <iostream> int main(){return 0;}` to `$sourcecode`?

Answer (score 1):

A subroutine in perl, is *defined* using `sub` and called using the subroutine name.

So a subroutine called `hash` (which is a really bad choice of name, because hashes are something else in Perl) would be defined:

```
sub hash($) { 
    my ( $first_arg ) = @_; 

    my $some_result = $first_arg;  

    return $some_result;
}
```

The `($)` in the subroutine definition is a prototype, which says 'this hash expects a single scalar'.

To call this subroutine:

```
 my $subroutine_output = hash("some test text");
```

It's as simple as that. (But seriously - don't call a subroutine `hash` - that's just asking for grief).